Creating forest plot using "robumeta". Returns a "chaotic" forest plot
#Create robust variance estimation model

rve_model <- robu(formula = yi ~ 1, data = df,
studynum = Study_name, var.eff.size = vi,
rho = 0.8, small = TRUE)'

#Forest plot

forest.robu(rve_model, es.lab = "yi", study.lab = "Study_name")'

My syntax does not return any errors and seems to work fine. And as you might see from the syntax, it clusters by "Study_name", which should return about 50 effect sizes (based on several effect sizes within each of the 50 studies) in my forest plot. However, the forest plot which is generated looks very strange.

Is there anything I am missing?
I have loaded the grid package, which the robumeta documentation says is required for creating the forest plot. All of the packages have alse been updated to the latest versions.
